# Alarm clock in Batch

Tags: batch-file, clock, alarm

I want to do an alarm clock in batch. I choose that I decide the time in the command line. For example: alarm.bat 12:00:00. Then with a loop I test if the time is the same and if this is right, I play a music. The problem is that %time% gives also the milliseconds and so the test never ends. I also tried to add milliseconds to the command line but it didn't work. Can you please give me a hand?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
:Loop
IF %1==%time% GOTO continue
GOTO Loop
:Continue
while :
start c:\music\"my song.mp3"
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this just as a learning experiment or for actual application?  If it's for actual application, I would recommend scheduled tasks instead.

Comment: How about using a substring to cut the milliseconds?

Comment: the title: Is this Bash or Batch?

Answer (score 0):

instead of time you can use date with: `date +%k:%m:%S`
this will return hours:minutes:seconds

i would also suggest a sleep command in the loop...

Answer (score 0):

you can extract part of the time variable like this:

%time:~0,8%

it's the time variable but only with 8 characters

Example:
so instead of "15:23:10.62" it will be "15:23:10"

also for a better alarm noise, you can loop the bell sound like this:

```
:Continue
echo (edit: missing character)
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
goto:Continue
```

the character is invisible...
the character is the BEL character. it will trigger the default beep.